# Horizontal ScrollView have a empty space in bottom

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a Horizontal ScrollView by code below:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#ff00ff'}}>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                    <Text>MauMau </Text>
                </ScrollView>
```

but it had an empty space in bottom like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUlHP.png)

So, could you tell me why we have this space and how to get rid with it?

**UPDATE 2022/05/27**

Just update my source code, I trying to custom the Tabbar in horizonal (since some point in Material top tabs that doesn't fit with my design) like below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
function CustomWidthTabsHeader({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
    const scrollRef = React.useRef();
    const listOffset = []
    const listWidth = []
    const [listItemOffsetX, setListItemOffsetX] = React.useState(listOffset);
    const [listItemWidth, setListItemWidth] = React.useState(listWidth);
    const [scrollViewWidth, setScrollViewWidth] = React.useState(0);
    const [scrollViewOffsetX, setScrollViewOffsetX] = React.useState(0);
    return (
            <ScrollView
                ref={scrollRef} horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                onScroll={event=>{
                    setScrollViewOffsetX(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
                }}
                onLayout={event => {
                    const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                    setScrollViewWidth(layout.width)
                }}>
                {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                    const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
                    const label =
                        options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
                            ? options.tabBarLabel
                            : options.title !== undefined
                                ? options.title
                                : route.name;
                    const badge = options.tabBarBadge
                    const isFocused = state.index === index;

                    const onPress = () => {
                        const event = navigation.emit({
                            type: 'tabPress',
                            target: route.key,
                        });

                        if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                            console.log("MauMau scrollview offsetX: " + scrollViewOffsetX + " Width: " + scrollViewWidth)
                            if (listItemOffsetX[index]<scrollViewOffsetX){
                                console.log("MauMau move to offsetX: " + listItemOffsetX[index] + " offsetY: " + index)
                                scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: listItemOffsetX[index], y: 0, animated: true })
                            } else if ((listItemOffsetX[index] +listItemWidth[index])>(scrollViewOffsetX +scrollViewWidth)){
                                scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: (listItemOffsetX[index] +listItemWidth[index]- scrollViewWidth), y: 0, animated: true })
                            }
                            
                            navigation.navigate(route.name);
                        }
                    };

                    const onLongPress = () => {
                        navigation.emit({
                            type: 'tabLongPress',
                            target: route.key,
                        });
                    };

                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            accessibilityRole="button"
                            accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
                            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
                            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
                            onPress={onPress}
                            key={index}
                            onLongPress={onLongPress}
                            onLayout={event => {
                                const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                                listOffset.push(layout.x)
                                listWidth.push(layout.width)
                                setListItemOffsetX(listOffset)
                                setListItemWidth(listWidth)
                                console.log("MauMau set listOffset: " + listOffset)
                            }}
                            style={{ alignItems: "flex-start", height: 35, borderBottomColor: '#F96300', borderBottomWidth: isFocused ? 4 : 0 }}
                        >
                            <Text style={{
                                color: isFocused ? '#F96300' : '#BDBDBD',
                                borderRadius: isFocused ? 8 : 0,
                                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                paddingVertical: 6,
                                paddingHorizontal: 12,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: '600'
                            }}>
                                {label}
                            </Text>
                            {badge > 0 ? <Text style={{
                                position: 'absolute',
                                right: -5,
                                top: -5,
                                width: 20,
                                height: 20,
                                borderRadius: 10,
                                backgroundColor: '#F96300',
                                textAlign: 'center',
                                color: '#fff'
                            }}>{badge}</Text> : null}
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                })}
            </ScrollView>

    );
}
export default CustomWidthTabsHeader
```

Comment: I think the padding comes from the Component that wraps your ScrollView, you should check that.

Comment: I tried to set margin:0 and padding:0 but it isn't working

Comment: Try removing flex:1 from style and add required height and width:'100%' instead

Comment: I tried but it also not working

Comment: Try adding `padding: 0` or `margin: 0` to your `<Text>`

Comment: You have a parent View with flex:1 right? if not try that also

Comment: you should edit your question to show us your full code

Comment: I tried to add padding: 0 and margin: 0 to ScrollView and <Text> but it not work.

Comment: show full code, the spacing is probably due to the parent View under which the scroll view is wrapped.

Comment: Just upload my full code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to fix this by put the ScrollView into a View like:

```
 <View>
                <ScrollView
                    ....>
                </ScrollView>
 </View>
```